# Android MediaRouter

Tags: appcelerator, appcelerator-titanium

I try to build a Titanium module for Mediarouter (Chromecast). The standard solution for it is the use a MediaRouteSelector that opens a dialog with elements of android-support-mediarouter.jar. If I build a demo app by using the chromecast module then the aapt tries to resolve dependencies to appcompat-v7. But a module can only work with one res folder.

My question: is it possible the get a mediaroute without UI? I mean to ask the android and the system give me a collection of connected  devices (name and id), I build an own dialog box and the result of users select calls a method to commect with this selected device. This solution would avoid the res conflict.

Here the repo: https://github.com/AppWerft/Ti.Chromecast/tree/master/android

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

MediaRoute has nothing to do with the UI itself. You can initiate a discovery on the local network for the routes that satisfy your search criteria and then register to be notified when a matching route is found or dropped out, etc. If you want to show your own UI, you'd need to manage the list yourself, both in terms of bookkeeping, interactions and presentation. Look at our Android sender documentation or one of our Android sample apps (e.g. [MediaRoute-Cast-Button sample](https://github.com/googlecast/MediaRouter-Cast-Button-android)) to get an idea.